# Setting up OAuth callback with I18n in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, internationalization, routes

In my Ruby on Rails app I have set up OAuth to work using the omniauth gem. Everything is working smoothly; however, I am having trouble getting it to work once I add I18n to the app.  Specifically, the issue is with the callback.  How can I adjust my routes.rb code to correctly handle the callback using I18n?

**routes.rb**

```
 scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
   resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
   root to: 'static_pages#home'

   match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
   match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
   match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

   match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
   match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
 end

  match '*path', to: redirect {|params| "/#{I18n.default_locale}/#{CGI::unescape(params[:path])}" }, constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
   before_filter :set_locale
     def set_locale
       I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
     end

     def default_url_options(options = {})
       {locale: I18n.locale}
     end
```

Comment: What is the exact nature of the issue? Can you add more details about the problem? e.g. Errors, something not happening, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900085/devise-and-i18n-reset-password-routing-issues). The :locale needs to be in parentheses: `scope "(:locale)"`